# How to listen Profile switch events on android?

Tags: android, android-managed-profile, android-work-profile

I have personal and work profiles. I wanted to get callback when user switches from one profile to another one

I tried ACTION_USER_SWITCHED intent action but it didn't help. Also tried to check ActivityManager isProfileForeground method but it always returned me true. I checked I have 2 users.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.